# Как изменить цвет шкалы в видео?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Cейчас, она белая, полоса, как можно поменять цвет и сделать синий или красной? Также вторая полоса серая, можно ли её цвет тоже менять?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.video {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: solid 3px #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay loop class="video" id="video" controls disablePictureInPicture controlsList="nodownload">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="1.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Никак. Это дефолтный плеер браузера и в разных браузерах плееры могут отличаться. Только если свои элементы плеера верстать и всё это дело подключать.

Comment: я не очень во фронт, но разве нельзя использовать мета-тэги, например, этот `video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline`

Comment: Написать свой плеер

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если говорить о кастомизации стандартного плеера в webkit-браузерах (не о сборке собственного), то можно разве что поиграть с CSS-фильтрами, чтобы целиком тонировать элемент управления timeline в какой-нибудь оттенок.

Как было верно подмечено в комментариях, для него есть соответствующий псевдоэлемент.

```css
.custom-timeline::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
  filter: sepia(100%) brightness(50%) saturate(2000%) hue-rotate(120deg) contrast(200%);
}
```

```html
<video class="custom-timeline" controls="controls" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'></video>
```

[image: Скриншот]

Список возможных -webkit-псевдоэлементов для видеоплеера:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider
video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline
video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display
video::-webkit-full-page-media::-webkit-media-controls-panel
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container
video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display
video::-webkit-media-controls-seek-back-button
video::-webkit-media-controls-seek-forward-button
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button
video::-webkit-media-controls-rewind-button
video::-webkit-media-controls-return-to-realtime-button
video::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button
```

Answer (score 2):

Подробнее об этом можно прочитать здесь: https://professorweb.ru/my/html/html5/level3/3_3.php

Я только постараюсь поверхностно пройтись по гайду(будет сделанно через JS, может есть решения и лучше о которых я не знаю):

Берём пример кода, он похож на ваш:

HTML5:

```html
<video id="videoPlayer" width="600" height="400">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
<div>
    <button onclick="play()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
    <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
    <button onclick="speedUp()">Быстрей</button>
    <button onclick="slowDown()">Медленее</button>
    <button onclick="normalSpeed()">Нормальная скорость</button>
</div>
```

Название кнопок говорит само за себя, но давайте на всякий случай остоновимся здесь:

JS:

```js
var video;
var display;

window.onload = function() {
    video = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
};

function play() {
    video.play();
}

function pause() {
    video.pause();
}

function stop() {
    video.pause();
    video.currentTime = 0;
}
```

Думаю что объяснять тут нечего, создаёте функцию с нужными вам действиями и добавляете ивент через JS или onclick="Название Функции" как в этом случае. Более подробнее про кнопки можете почитать в гайде.

Приступаем  к самому главному, к прогресс бару, создаете подобный код:

```html
<div class="barContainer">
  <div id="durationBar">
    <div id="positionBar"><span id="displayStatus">0</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Возможно использование тега progress, но в этом случае мы используем 2 дива.
Далее даём стили прогресс бару:

```css
#positionBar {
   height: 30px;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   background: steelblue;
   text-align: center;
}

#positionBar span {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: 5px;
}

#durationBar {
   border: solid 1px black;
   width: 100%;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Есстественно его можно поменять под свои нужды и под свой дизайн. Далее подключаем video под кастомный прогресс бар:

```html
<video id="videoPlayer" onTimeUpdate="progressUpdate()">
...
```

Всё почти готово осталось написать пару строк JS кода:

```js
function progressUpdate() {
    // Устанавливаем позицию воспроизведения
    var positionBar = document.getElementById("positionBar");
    positionBar.style.width = (video.currentTime / video.duration * 100)  + "%";
    
    // Заполняем текстовую надпись текущим значением
    displayStatus = document.getElementById("displayStatus");
    displayStatus.innerHTML = (Math.round(video.currentTime*100)/100) + " сек";
  }
```

В 1 варианте он устанавливает только заполняемость шкалы, во 2 указывает процент и надпись на прогресс баре.

Но это достаточно кастыльный метод создания не советую вас его использовать, достаточно использовать 1 фрэймворк по типу Video.js(https://videojs.com/); там всё в 20 раз удобнее, понятнее и легче